# How to reset the JDBC Connection Pool

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a problem where I get tomcat exceptions after I reset my MySQL database at the request of the user via a tomcat web app.  I've tried to break this up into the setup, problem, and my analysis so far to help anyone trying to read this.

## Setup

The reset basically consists of calling a bash script from the java code to:

- Removing the root mysql user password
- Loading in an old version of the database
- Running some scripts on it
- Restoring all the passwords

It is a user initiated procedure to usually restore the database to a previous state, but it is also be used to import a database from another system.  Once everything is complete, the user then attempts to access a different portion of the web app (i.e. with the same session without logging out/logging back in) which performs a DB query to get some data.

## Problem

Once the DB is queried by the tomcat application, there is an exception:

```
Dec 29, 2014 3:49:50 PM ERROR BasicSecurityRealm:216 - 
ERROR: ----- SQLException -----

Dec 29, 2014 3:49:50 PM  INFO BasicSecurityRealm:218 - Exceptioncom.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 234,810 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 12 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:2540)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:2990)
```

Even if the user logs out and back in, I will see this exception.  If I refresh the page, four times, the page will load a little bit more each time with some different exceptions (all variations of the above - CommunicationsException caused by "EOFException: Can not read response from server").  The final time, everything seems to be running normally.

The only thing that I can do to avoid these exceptions is to restart tomcat.  I would like to avoid this because it will mean that the current user who is logged in will lose their session and have to wait for tomcat to restart before they can log back in.  Forcing them to log out/back in might be an acceptable compromise, but that doesn't solve the problem anyway.

## Analysis

From what I can tell, I think that the problem has to do with the JDBC connection pool.  I am using JNDI data sources to access my database as follows:

server.xml:

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/mydb"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="30" maxIdle="30" maxWait="2147483647"
              username="x" password="x"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true"/>
```

web.xml:

```
<!-- Data source definitions -->
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/mydb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

Java:

```
    // Get connection to specified database
    Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
    Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/mydb");
    con = ds.getConnection();
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("...");
```

I believe that the connection pool contains connections that are stale/dead.  Whenever I get a connection with `ds.getConnection`, then it is getting one of these old connections.  Attempts to use it will fail the first time and the connection is reset (notice that I am using `autoReconnect=true`, so the second time should (and does) work).  However, the pool contains many (in my case, empirically 4 or 5) stale connections, so it takes a while before they are all properly reset.  Once a connection is reset, everything behaves properly.

## Solutions?

Since I use `autoReconnect=true` I could re-structure my code so that if I get an exception when I attempt a query, I can retry the query once.  If it fails again, then I would know that there is really a problem.  If it passes, then the connection was successfully re-established.

The problem with this is that there are queries EVERYWHERE in the code.  Re-factoring them all would take a lot of time and testing, which I will do if necessary, but would like to avoid.  Also, if the query is failing for other reasons, then it would be attempted twice before being reported.  For long queries, this could have a significant user experience delay, but only in error conditions.

Another solution would be to force a reset/reconnect of all connections in the connection pool.  I could do this either programmatically (i.e. from my java code when the invocation of the bash script completes) or from the bash script (e.g. with some type of command line utility).  The problem is, I don't know how to do this, or if it is even possible.

I've found some documentation on Interceptors, but I am not sure if that would work for resetting a connection.  I will continue to investigate.

Thanks everyone for your time and help!

Comment: Solution: do not remove the credentials for the user you have configured in your database connection pool. In fact, you should not mess with mysql user data in order to alter the state of your database. You should only change the schema you're working with.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks.  I had thought of that, but long story short, that might not be an option.  The script that runs does not have the credentials to modify the database, so I need to remove the password for the root user.  Also, the new database which is loaded might have different passwords.

Comment: *I had thought of that, but long story short, that might not be an option* then suffer in silence u_u. Jokes apart, you cannot *reset* a database connection pool. Avoid doing this, or execute your script with a user that has enough power to do it. You could create another user to do so, or shutdown your apps and start them again and establish policies for this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The problem isn't having a user with the power, it is getting the password to the script.  The scripts that run right now assume the root user has no password - it lets them run mysql without the password.  If I don't reset the password, then the scripts would need to take the password as an argument or input, and pass it to mysql command line as an argument or input.  Again, a huge change since the scripts call mysql command line hundreds of times.

Comment: I guess your whole approach gives you this problem and you're trying to use a dirty trick to solve your design. My recommendation is: yes, send this password as argument to the script and forget about even messing with mysql user credentials **at all**. That's the problem, no matter how you depict it, and you should avoid that step and use cleaner designs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Sending the password as an argument is a bit of a security problem since "ps" will report the full command line.  Even mysql does only a half-assed job of fixing this by attempting to write "XXXX" over the password portion of the command line argument.  This is half-assed because there is a small window where the password is in plain text.  A script or programs which constantly monitors running processes and the command lines could easily find the password when this script runs.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I understand that the code is not designed properly at the moment, but we all inherit code that isn't always the best and are forced to live with it.  I was hoping for something that might work in spite of the design, but perhaps I am out of luck.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Actually, the problem also occurs if I do a service mysqld stop/start and then try to access my web GUI again.  So it doesn't have anything to do with the removal of credentials or the running of scripts.

Comment: If you understand how a database connection pool works, then you should not be surprised of this result if you restart your database engine. The solution, again, is not reset the connection pool, but establishing policies to restart your database engine. If you're going to restart your engine, restart your apps as well.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza So you are saying that if mysql is restarted for any reason, I need to restart tomcat as well?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I understand how connection pools work.  I know that if mysql is restarted then all the connections are invalid.  With the autoReconnect=true flag, applications can recover after the first exception, so reconnecting is obviously possible.  I find it surprising that tomcat applications cannot handle a minor thing like a temporary loss of connection without requiring a full restart.  How would one even enforce that with policy?  It seems like a manual step is required to restart tomcat, or some cron job that tests to see if the PID of mysql has changed and force a restar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can test connection before getting from the pool

By default Tomcat <7 uses [commond-dbcp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html) for Tomcat >= 7 it's [jdbc-pool](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html)

In both cases add next properties to connection pool configuration:

```
validationQuery=<TEST SQL>
testOnBorrow=true
```

Comment: This looks like the right approach. Make sure you verify the validationInterval property of the pool. It is by default 30 secs which means if the connection was tested in last 30 sec, the validation query will not be executed. In your use case it seems you might have to make the validationInterval to 0.

Comment: @AndyDufresne Seems to work.  However, if I know all connections in the pool are stale, is there no way to force a reset of them all?  That would be more efficient than checking every time.

Comment: Didn't find any API to do that. Does purge() help?

Comment: @AndyDufresne on what object?

Comment: The connectionPool object which is returned when you call datasource.createPool()

Answer (score 0):

That exception will raise due to your project contain multiple `ojdbc` jars like (`ojdbc6 or ojdbc14`) at that moment you may get exception when you are trying to connect oracle `12c` remove all `ojdbc` jars in your project and add any one jar only recommended one is `ojdbc7` jar.

Comment: You can edit the existing answer of yours if you think you can add more information. Avoid adding two answers to a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can test connection before getting from the pool.

Add in connection pool configuration:

```
validationQuery=TEST SQL
testOnBorrow=true
```